# How to change an object from a method within its class

Tags: java

In java, is it possible to change an Object instance from within a method of its class? I would like to do something like this:

```
public void setMix(MyColor[] colors){

    MyColor colorMix = MyColor.colorMixer(colors);

    // Instead of this
    this.red = colorMix.getRed();
    this.blue = colorMix.getBlue();
    this.green = colorMix.getGreen();

    // I would like to do something like:
//  this = colorMix; 
    // which is not allowed

}



public static MyColor colorMixer(MyColor[] colors){

    int red = 0;
    int green = 0;
    int blue = 0;

    ...
    // Here I work with the colors array to compute three new components


    return new MyColor(red, green, blue);
}
```

Is there a nice way to do that? Thanks a lot!

[I'm sure this question should have been answered before, but I couldn't find it, I'm sorry if it's the case]

Comment: No. That is not possible. It really depends on what you want to do specifically. You could replace all the references to the current object with a clone/instance of the one you create inside that class, but I'm not sure if that is what you want

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do (reassigning `this`) is not possible, at least not in java.

Suppose you have following class:

```
class Foo {
  MyColor color;
  public Foo(Mycolor color) {
    this.color = color;
  }
}
```

And the following instances:

```
MyColor color = new MyColor();
Foo foo = new Foo(color);
```

Suppose you could reassign `this` in MyColor somehow, then what you would get is a new instance of MyColor, but `foo.color` would still point to the old MyColor instance.

What you can do instead is just let the color instance change it's internal state. That way every other object which holds a reference to that color instance will have the "new" color object.

Answer (score 1):

> In java, is it possible to change an Object instance from within a method of its class? I

**Yes**   you can , and here is the most common example

```
class Person{
    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;//setting name 
    }

}
```

if you want to assign something to `this` then its not possible its `final`

Comment: you changed a member of a object, not replacing the object with a new one inside the object's method! wrong answer i think!

Answer (score 0):

Doing `this = new MyColor()` is not possible in an instance method. It seems that you need a factory, a static method like Integer.valueOf(2), to access configured instance of a class.

If you want to configure an objet in several steps, the pattern Builder is a good start.